# How do I sample a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, downsampling

I have a matrix in MATLAB from which I want to sample every other entry:

```
a =

     1     5     9    13
     2     6    10    14
     3     7    11    15
     4     8    12    16
```

And I want:

```
result =

     1     9    
     3    11
```

How can I do this without a for loop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know of a multi-dimensional way to do it automatically, but Matlab's indexing is good enough if you're happy to specify it for each dimension:

```
a(1:2:end,1:2:end)
```

Comment: +1: Somehow I forgot to include the `end` syntax in my answer. Good catch. ;)

Answer (score 5):

This should work for your specific example:

```
result = a([1 3],[1 3]);
```

and more generally:

```
result = a(1:2:size(a,1),1:2:size(a,2));
```

For more details about indexing in MATLAB, you can check out the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html).

Answer (score 2):

I found this today. `A` is the original matrix, sampled every s element.

```
Adown=downsample(downsample(A,s)',s)'
```

It down-samples the matrix vertically, transposes, then samples the orthogonal direction, then transposes back.

Answer (score 1):

```
samples_x = floor(linspace(1, size(a,1), new_Nx));
samples_y = floor(linspace(1, size(a,2), new_Ny));
new_a = a(samples_x,samples_y)
```

Comment: +1 and welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be even more useful if you explained in a few words what your code does. Feel free to use the edit link below your question...